# GAS: key:value array to menu

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So i am attempting to turn a key:value array into a menu using Google Apps Script. I am using SpreadsheetApp currently but want to make this for use in other apps.

My issue is using `context_menu()` method gives an error of `Exception: Custom menus must contain at least one item.` on line `m.addToUi()` in `context_menu()`

I have tested this using `simple_menu()` to make sure i understand how it works (and that works perfectly) so I'm not sure what the issue is.

```js
var f = 'my_function'
var m_contex = {"Item1":f, "Item2":f, "SubMenu":{"subItem1":f, "subItem2":f}, "Item3":f}

function my_function(){
  Logger.log("triggered");
}

function cm_rec(ui, m, name, items){
  var sm = ui.createMenu(name);
  m.addSubMenu(sm);
  for(var key in items){
    if(typeof items[key] === "string"){
      Logger.log("adding " + key + " to "+name);
      sm.addItem(key, items[key]);
    }else{
      cm_rec(ui, sm, key, items[key]);
    }
  }
}
function context_menu(ui, title, items){
  var m = ui.createMenu(title);
  for(var key in items){
    if(typeof items[key] === "string"){
      Logger.log("adding " + key + " to "+title);
      m.addItem(key, items[key]);
    }else{
      cm_rec(ui, m, key, items[key]);
    }
  }
  m.addToUi();
}

function simple_submenu(ui, m, title){
  var sm = ui.createMenu(title);
  sm.addItem("SubItem1", 'my_function');
  sm.addItem("SubItem2", 'my_function');
  m.addSubMenu(sm);
}
function simple_menu(ui){
  var m = ui.createMenu("My Menu");
  m.addItem("Item1", 'my_function');
  m.addItem("Item2", 'my_function');
  simple_submenu(ui, m, "SubMenu");
  m.addItem("Item3", 'my_function');
  m.addToUi();
}

function tester1(){ //runs the simple_menu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Logger.log("Creating Simple Menu");
  simple_menu(ui);
}
function tester2(){ // runs the context_menu
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Logger.log(m_contex);
  context_menu(ui, "Custom Menu", m_contex);
}
```

The output for tester2 is correct except from the error:

```
2:44:27 PM  Info    {Item3=my_function, Item1=my_function, SubMenu={subItem2=my_function, subItem1=my_function}, Item2=my_function}
2:44:27 PM  Info    adding Item1 to Custom Menu
2:44:27 PM  Info    adding Item2 to Custom Menu
2:44:27 PM  Info    adding subItem1 to SubMenu
2:44:27 PM  Info    adding subItem2 to SubMenu
2:44:27 PM  Info    adding Item3 to Custom Menu
```

Comment: Personally I don't wish to debug you entire code.  Please ask a more focused question.  In other words do the code debugging yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, I thought that the following part might be required to be modified.

```
var sm = ui.createMenu(name);
m.addSubMenu(sm);
```

Because, in this case, `sm` is added with no items. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Exception: Custom menus must contain at least one item.`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, please modify the function `cm_rec` as follows.

```js
function cm_rec(ui, m, name, items) {
  var sm = ui.createMenu(name);
  for (var key in items) {
    if (typeof items[key] === "string") {
      Logger.log("adding " + key + " to " + name);
      sm.addItem(key, items[key]);
    } else {
      cm_rec(ui, sm, key, items[key]);
    }
  }
  m.addSubMenu(sm); // This line was moved.
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did indeed work perfectly. seems GAS doesn't evaluate the menu object during the `addToUi()` method like i assumed, and instead only looks at it during the `addSubMenu()` this is not clear in the docs and they all used the simple method I used as an example.